# Reserved python keywords are not longer showed in green (or any color)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently noticed that some python keyword are not more colored in green. I remember having `str`, `int` and `float`, among others, to have a green color indicating that those words are reserved words, but now they are plain white (like any other common variable). How can I fix this? I'm using:

- jupyter lab 4.0.8
- python 3.9
- node 18.15.0
- npm 9.5.0

[image]

EDIT: It seems this has nothing to do with a theme thing. I ran jupyter lab in other environment and it displays the mentioned keywords as expected. Adding image of this.

[image]

Comment: The first set are keywords, the second are functions.  Used `if x:` versus `str(12)` and `print(12)`.  Functions can be redefined.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj. Yes, the second ones are functions, but the used to be green. Like "reserved" functions. Now they are just plain white.

Comment: maybe you should check if `jupyter lab` uses some file to define `reserved` word and colors.  But programs may need `(`after function's name to recognize if it is function or normal variable. So maybe you should check `str(`, `int(`, `float(` instead of `str`, `int`, `float`. And even `my_private_function(` instead of `my_private_function`

Comment: BTW: using Google I found article: [A theme editor for JupyterLab.](https://blog.jupyter.org/a-theme-editor-for-jupyterlab-8f08ab62894d)